# ccall with mutable vs immutable struct

Tags: julia

How does Julia handle `ccall` when the return type has **mutable structs** vs when it has **immutable structs**?

Here's a simple library that has `get_foos()` function which returns a struct that has another struct with one member double.

```c
typedef struct _Foo {
    double a;
} Foo;

typedef struct _Foos {
    Foo foo_a;
} Foos;

Foos get_foos() {
    Foos foos;
    foos.foo_a.a = 1 ;
    return foos;
}
```

The following Julia code prints `Foos(Foo(1.0))` as expected:

```py
using Libdl

struct Foo 
    a::Cdouble
end

struct Foos
    foo_a::Foo
end

function get_foos()
    sdk_dll = Libdl.dlopen("libfos") 
    f = Libdl.dlsym(sdk_dll, :get_foos)
    return ccall(f, Foos, ())
end

show(get_foos())
```

But if the inner struct is **mutable**, I get a segfault.

```py
mutable struct Foo 
    a::Cdouble
end

struct Foos
    foo_a::Foo
end
```

Julia 1.1, on Linux and OSX.

I'm assuming it's not a bug, but couldn't find enough information to figure out why that's happening.